# Как отключить синхронизацию в slick слайдере?

Tags: html, css, slider, slick.js

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,

  arrows: false,
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  //fade: true,  

});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  //lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  //infinite: false,
  slidesToScroll: 1,

  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  arrows: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  touchThreshold: true,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1025,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
$('.slider-nav').on('wheel', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  }
}));
$(".slick-slide", '.slider-nav').click(function() {
  $('.slider-for').slick('slickGoTo', $(this).index(), true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides">
  <div class="slider-for">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-1"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-2"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-3"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-4"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-5"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-nav">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=1"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=2"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=3"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=4"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=5"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть такой слайдер : https://imperiumloft.ru/dizajn-loft/178094-26.html

А нужно,как тут : https://www.ozon.ru/product/proteinovoe-pechene-brauni-bez-sahara-shocks-assorti-shokoladnyy-kofe-s-molokom-arahisovaya-958074205/?avtc=1&avte=1&avts=1693847703&sh=uksnsQTHeA

То есть у озона слайдера можно листать без пролистывания главного фото,когда листаешь курсором мышкой или с помощью стрелкой,то другое фото не появляется,пока не выберешь сам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрать связь слайдеров, в настройках у дочернего и родителя - это `asNavFor: '.slider-nav'`

Добавить код чтобы менять родительский по дочернему. Раз слайдер зацикленный, то брать не сам индекс, а атрибут data-slick-index - вот он ближе к реальному.

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  arrows: false,
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  //fade: true,  

});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  //lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  //infinite: false,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  arrows: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  touchThreshold: true,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1025,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
$('.slider-nav').on('wheel', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  }
}));
$('.slick-slide', '.slider-nav').click(function() {
  $('.slider-for').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt($(this).attr('data-slick-index')), true);
});

$('.slider-nav').on('wheel', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
        $(this).slick('slickNext');
    } else {
        $(this).slick('slickPrev');
    }
}));
```

```css
.slides {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%
}

.slider-for {
  width: 200px;
}

.slider-nav {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides">
  <div class="slider-for">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-1"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-2"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-3"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-4"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-5"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=Photo-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-nav">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=1"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=2"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=3"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=4"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=5"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cccccc/E0F6FD?text=6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я добавил код слайдера в вопрос,посмотрите пожалуйста,правильно ли всё?

Comment: общую идею уловили, но споткнулись на настройках слайдера. Добавила в свой ответ работающий пример.

Comment: как можно листать быстро?Без затыканий слайдов?Тоесть в вашем примере и в моём слайдере тоже,когда пролистнул 1 слайд,то останавливается,а нужно,чтобы можно было листать без затыканий,как скролл.Как говорил @Levitskyi я убрал этот участок кода,но вообще не листается

Comment: код для скролла мышью не особо связан с кликами, проблема некорректных нажатий от него не зависела. Т.е. вернуть код и будет мышью листаться.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте закомментировать этот код:

```
$('.slider-nav').on('wheel', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
        $(this).slick('slickNext');
    } else {
        $(this).slick('slickPrev');
    }
}));
```

Если дело не в нём, то скорее всего нужно будет отвязать друг от друга эти два слайдера, а чтоб при клике по превьюшке менялось основное фото - переписать с использованием метода ***slickGoTo***

Comment: @Kjuri как можно убрать это в самих настройках slick?То есть файлы устанавливаются же при установке slick,а это файлы slick js,slick min js и так далее

Comment: как можно убрать это в самих настройках slick?То есть файлы устанавливаются же при установке slick,а это файлы slick js,slick min js и так далее

Comment: Вам не нужно лезть в дистрибутив Slick, он работает так, как ему указали разработчики вашего шаблона сайта, все настройки слайдера у вас в шаблоне.
Потому править нужно шаблон, а не Slick.

Файл в котором скорее всего у вас настройки Slick - catalog/view/theme/zendtheme/template/product/product.twig (либо product.tpl если у вас Opencart версии 2.x)

Выше Kjuri даже написал готовый код к тому, что я описал словами.

Comment: как можно убрать затыкания?Теперь листается как нужно,но свободно листать нельзя,когда пролистнул 1 слайдер,то останавливается,а нужно быстро без затыканий,чтобы они вообще не были

Comment: У вас всё сломалось, отображается не то фото которое нажато, скорее всего потому что вы взяли код который дал Kjuri но не сделали всё что он сказал - не отвязали слайдеры друг от друга. Чтоб убрать "затыкания", попробуйте временно закомментировать код который я дал в своём ответе, он как раз отвечает за прокрутку колесом.

Comment: я закомментировал участок кода,который вы говорили,но теперь вообще не листается

Comment: Если у вас возник вопрос как закомментировать - у вас нулевой уровень знания JS, я бы советовал вернуть из резервной копии всё как было и обратиться к кому-то кто выполнит эту работу. Я не из вредности это говорю - в коде уже хаос и есть ошибки, дальше будет только хуже. Что касается скролла мышью - да, это не поможет, код можно вернуть обратно (раскомментировать, но вы его уже удалили). Суть проблемы в том что Slick листает всегда кратно слайдам, а в озоне скролл может остановиться в любой позиции (например на середине слайда или в любом другом месте).

Comment: Если хотите чтоб листалось быстрее - то как компромисс выставить значение slidesToScroll кратно количеству отображаемых слайдов, например на десктопе отображается 4 и нужно выставить 4, тогда колесом будет прокручиваться сразу 4 слайда. Это не как в озоне, но лучше чем сейчас. Ну естественно нужно предусмотреть, что в планшетной или мобильной версии другое кол-во слайдов, и прокрутка должна им соответствовать (т.е. там выставить другие значения). Я нарочно не привожу код, чтоб не усугублять ситуацию еще сильнее. Верните из бэкапа как было, и начните всё с начала.